# calling SOAP web service from PL/SQL

Tags: soap, plsql

I have a .net SOAP and I want to call it from PL/SQL

```
DECLARE


-- SOAP REQUESTS/RESPONSE
   soap_req_msg    VARCHAR2 (2000);
   soap_resp_msg   VARCHAR2 (2000);

   -- HTTP REQUEST/RESPONSE
   http_req        UTL_HTTP.req;
   http_resp       UTL_HTTP.resp;

BEGIN
   --
   -- Create SOAP request via HTTP
   --
   soap_req_msg := 
      '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1d66c9a8-b5e2-4c7a-9649-0bd63a590372</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/IDataInterfaceService/Connect</wsa:Action><wsa:To>http://localhost:3038/</wsa:To></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns1:Connect xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

   http_req :=UTL_HTTP.begin_request('http://localhost:3038/', 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDataInterfaceService/Connect"');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_req_msg));
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Host', 'localhost:3038');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'User-Agent', 'Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)');
   UTL_HTTP.write_text (http_req, soap_req_msg);

  dbms_output.put_line(' ');
  --
   -- Invoke Request and get Response.
   --
   http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_req);
   UTL_HTTP.read_text (http_resp, soap_resp_msg);
   UTL_HTTP.end_response (http_resp);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Output: ' || soap_resp_msg);
END;
/
```

The request is doing fine inSOAPUI. But not in the PL/SQL

Here is the response:

```
Output: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Wondering what's wrong with my header name.... Anyone can help me please?

ADDITION: This is the RAW XML copy from SOAPUI

```
POST http://localhost:3038/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDataInterfaceService/Connect"
Content-Length: 441
Host: localhost:3038
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1d66c9a8-b5e2-4c7a-9649-0bd63a590372</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/IDataInterfaceService/Connect</wsa:Action><wsa:To>http://localhost:3038/</wsa:To></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns1:Connect xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing this line

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Host', 'localhost:3038');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the Content-Type header into 2 headers:

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8');
UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_req, 'SOAPAction','"http://tempuri.org/IDataInterfaceService/Connect"');
```